# get sum of hours grouped by hours as Rows and month as column?

Tags: sql-server

i try to get sum of Hours as Rows and split it by month  as column to get result final as:

```
Hours                   Jan        Feb           Mar

08:00 To 08:59          1000     3500       2000

09:00 To 09:59         5000    6000       12000

ect ....................
```

the field i work around is DateTime and values on it as:

> 2014-01-01 08:02:34.000

i try it by query:

```
SELECT   EntryDate, sum(LTOT) AS InvoiceTotal,

     sum(DATEPART(SECOND, EntryDate) + 60 * 
         DATEPART(MINUTE, EntryDate) + 3600 * 
         DATEPART(HOUR, EntryDate) 
        ) as 'TotalTime'

 FROM    AZTRH WHERE TR_TY = '102' AND

             LOC = '011' AND

             (CAST(AZTRH.EntryDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-02') AND

             (CAST(AZTRH.EntryDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:00:00.000' AND '09:59:59.000') 

GROUP BY AZTRH.EntryDate, LTOT  

ORDER BY EntryDate
```

so please how can i get result as i need ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
;WITH PivotSource
AS (
    SELECT  DATEPART(HOUR, t.EntryDate) AS EntryHour,
            MONTH(t.EntryDate) AS EntryMonth,
            t.LTOT
    FROM    ... 
    WHERE   ... 
)
SELECT  STR(p.EntryHour, 2, 0) + ':00 To' + STR(p.EntryHour, 2, 0)+':59'  AS [Hours],
        p.[1] AS Jan,
        p.[2] AS Feb,
        ...
FROM    PivotSource AS s
PIVOT( SUM(s.LTOT) FOR s.EntryMonth IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) ) AS p
```

It uses:

- `DATEPART(HOUR, D/T value)` to *extract* hour part from EntryDate,
- `MONTH(D/T value)` to *extract* month number (1, 2, ..., 12),
- and [PIVOT operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to compute `SUM` for every hour and month.